# How to speed up file change from host into docker container?

Tags: docker

My host is MacOS with DockerDesktop. I have a Debian container in which a PHP application is running. Parts of the PHP application are part of the docker image, the parts I am still working on are shared with the host through a volume. Think of

`docker run -td --name my-app -v /Users/me/mycode:/var/www/html/phpApp/variableParts`

**My problem**: When I save a change on the host it takes some 10-15 seconds until this change becomes available to the containerized app. So (1) after every save it takes (too) long waiting for the code to be available and (2) I cannot be sure whether I already see the new code running or still the old one.

My problem is **not** that the execution of the application is slow (as some sources in the web suggest), in fact it is quite fast. My problem is that the *time for the change to propagate from the host to the docker container* is too long. Earlier I developed and had the code from the remote server NFS-mounted on my developing machine and there it was blazing fast.

Is there any way I can reasonably speed this up? Or does a different workflow make more sense? Would mounting the code parts I want to edit from the container (as NFS server) to the host (where the editor runs) make sense?

My workflow consists of many small adaptations to be made to the PHP code, so waitint 10-15 seconds after every edit is a no-go.

Comment: What PHP runtime are you using? Does it load the PHP file from disk on every page load?

Comment: A better workflow would be to develop your application locally and use docker in its intended way, namely to put your final code inside the image on build and ship it without any volume shenanigans. Volumes can be useful to persist data or maybe for some configuration, but not for actual code.

Comment: It is a mediawiki 1.37.0 installation. I am working on an extension. I use PHP7.4 with apcu and opcache turned on. On my old server solution I see immediate reaction to my code edits. But wait a minute! I realize that in the docker image I have an opcache.revalidate_frequ=60 and on my other server I do not use opcache settings at all. That might be the reason. I'check, and if it is the reason, shame on me and a beer for you.

Comment: @The Fool: Actually I am using docker in order not to have umpteenth different local settings on my machine to be maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Docker on Mac, and have seen edits to a bind mount propagate to the Docker container in under a second, so I think Docker is not to blame here.

Instead, I would look at any caching that PHP is doing. Is PHP reloading your code from disk on every page view, or does it cache it? For example, the opcache feature of PHP keeps a pre-compiled version of your PHP code in memory, and occasionally checks if that version is still up to date. Take a look at your php.ini, and in particular what [opcache.revalidate_freq](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.revalidate-freq) is set to.